# Grouping / counting in javascript using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts, underscore.js

I am new to javascript (and to Stack Overflow) and I've encountered a problem I can't seem to solve. I am trying to generate a simple pie chart that shows the number of Projects for each value of Technology in my data. This is the kind of data I am working with:

- [Project1, Java]
- [Project2, Excel]
- [Project3, SAS]
- [Project4, Java]

The pie ratio in the example above would be 2:1:1.

The first part of my code loads the data and pushes it to an array, "techArray", that contains [project, tech]. This part works ok - I've verified it in a simplified version of the code.

I then want to group the array "techArray" and count the instances of each tech. To do so I'm using the Underscore library, as follows:

```
var chartData = [];
var techData = _.groupBy(techArray, 'tech');
_.each(techData, function(row) {
    var techCount = row.length;
    chartData = push( {
        name: row[0].tech,
        y: techCount
    });
});
```

The script then renders the chartData array using highcharts. Again, I have verified that this section works using a simplified (ungrouped) version.

There must be an issue with the grouping/counting step outlined above because I am seeing no output, but I simply can't find where. I am basing my solution on the following worked example: [Worked example](http://www.sharepointdeveloperhq.com/2013/05/utilizing-spservices-for-sharepoint-2010-to-create-charts-with-high-charts/).

If anyone can spot the error in what I've written, or propose another way of grouping the array, I'd be very grateful. This seems like it should be a simpler task than it's proving to be.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[countBy](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy) could be used instead of groupBy:

```
var techArray = [
    { project: 'Project1', tech: 'Java'},
    { project: 'Project2', tech: 'Excel'},
    { project: 'Project3', tech: 'SAS'},
    { project: 'Project4', tech: 'Java'},
];

var counts = _.countBy(techArray,'tech');
```

This will return an object with the tech as properties and their value as the count:

```
{ Java: 2, Excel: 1, SAS: 1 }
```

To get the data in the form for highcharts use map instead of each:

```
var data = _.map(counts, function(value, key){
    return {
        name: key,
        y: value
    };
});
```

Comment: suppose I have this json:
[{couponid: 500
locationid: 10
},{couponid: 600
locationid: 15
},
 {
  couponid: 500
  locationid: 10
 },
 {
  couponid: 500
  locationid: 20
 }
]

Using the solution given by you, I got an array of Unique coupon ids,
with counts for each unique coupon id; it was the most concise anwer I found after lot of searhcing;Can you please tell, now how can i get, for each unique couponid, how many unique location ids ?
ie in the above couponid 500 would have 2, and couponid 600 would have 1. Shall I post this as a separate question ?

Comment: @Bhargava I would post a new question if I were you so that you can get the benefit of many different people answering our question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var techArray = [['Project1','Java'], ['Project2', 'excel'], ['Project3', 'Java']];

var chartData = [];
var techData = _.groupBy(techArray, function(item) {
    return item[1];
});
_.each(techData, function(value, key) {
    var techCount = value.length;
    chartData.push({
        name: key,
        y: techCount
    });
});
```

`_.groupBy` needs to either get a property name, or a function that returns the value being grouped. There is no `tech` property of an array, so you cant group by it. But, as our `techArray` is an array of tuples, we can pass a function `_.groupBy` that returns the value that we want to groupBy, namely the second item in each tuple.

`chartData` now looks like this:

```
[{
    name: 'Java',
    y: 2
}, {
    name: 'excel',
    y: 1
}]
```